# How to add curly brace below xytree nodes

Tags: braces, trees

I would like to add a curly brace and label underneath the E and F nodes of an xytree like this:

[image]

So far, I have the code for the tree, but haven't been able to figure out how to insert the curly brace and label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xytree}
\begin{document}

\xytree{
&&& \xynode{A} \xyconnect{2,-2}"_{Yes}" \xyconnect{2,2}"^{No}" &&& \\
&&&&&& \\
& \xynode{B} \xyconnect{2,-1}"_{Yes}" \xyconnect{2,1}"^{No}" &&&& \xynode{C} \xyconnect{2,-1}"_{Yes}" \xyconnect{2,1}"^{No}" \\
&&&&&& \\
\xynode{\begin{tabular}{c}D\end{tabular}} && \xynode{E} && \xynode{F} &&     \xynode{\begin{tabular}{c}G\end{tabular}} \\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I can't offer you a solution, just one tip on the `forest` package, in case it would be difficult to handle it using the `xytree` package.

Comment: @Malipivo, thanks for pointing me to `forest`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option using `TikZ` and its [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) (to place marks at the beginning and end of where the brace should be) and `decorations.pathmorphing` (to place the brace with the text) libraries (compile two or three times for the code to stabilize):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xytree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\xytree{
&&& \xynode{A} \xyconnect{2,-2}"_{Yes}" \xyconnect{2,2}"^{No}" &&& \\
&&&&&& \\
& \xynode{B} \xyconnect{2,-1}"_{Yes}" \xyconnect{2,1}"^{No}" &&&& \xynode{C} \xyconnect{2,-1}"_{Yes}" \xyconnect{2,1}"^{No}" \\
&&&&&& \\
\xynode{\begin{tabular}{c}D\end{tabular}} && \xynode{\tikzmark{a}E} && \xynode{F\tikzmark{b}} &&     \xynode{\begin{tabular}{c}G\end{tabular}} \\
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  (pic cs:a) -- node[below=6pt] {label} (pic cs:b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you could be interested in the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package for drawing your trees; this package is very powerful and versatile and it is built upon PGF/TikZ, so the integration with TikZ code is very natural. Here's some code showing how to get the same result using the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
yes/.style={
  edge label={node[midway,left,font=\footnotesize,xshift=-3pt]{Yes}}
},
no/.style={
  edge label={node[midway,right,font=\footnotesize,xshift=3pt]{No}}
},
for tree={
  parent anchor=south, 
  child anchor=north,
  l sep=1cm,
  s sep=1cm
}
[A
  [B,yes 
    [D,yes] 
    [E,no,name=a]
  ]
  [C,no
    [F,yes,name=b] 
    [G,no]
  ]
]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
  (a.south west) -- node[below] {label} (b.south east);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you increase the vertical space between the braces and the text below it. Also, if the nodes are squared, how can you make the brace start from the node center and not its outer edges?